# Injectivity of some natural restriction map.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a group and $M,N$ be $G$-modules.

If $M_1$ is a $G$-submodule, then the restriction map $\operatorname{Hom}_G(M,N) \to\operatorname{Hom}_G(M_1,N)$ is injective map?

I think it is not true. But I found that someone used this argument in his proof. I am wondering whether there is some conditions on $G$-modules $M_1, M, N$ which makes this true.If such conditions exist, then it is reasonable to proceed it as he claims.

Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: What happens if $M_1=\{0\}$?

Comment: It is clearly true if $N = 0$. It is usually false if $M_1 = 0$. To find reasonable condition, surrounding settings might matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the exact sequence $0\to M_1\to M\to M/M_1\to 0$; applying $\operatorname{Hom}_G({-},N)$ yields the exact sequence
$$
0\to
\operatorname{Hom}_G(M/M_1,N)\to
\operatorname{Hom}_G(M,N)\to
\operatorname{Hom}_G(M_1,N)
$$
and the last map is precisely the restriction you mention.

Injectivity holds if and only if $\operatorname{Hom}_G(M/M_1,N)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is exactly what I am searching.